# Select the color of row based on end point JSON value using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have a program written in AngularJS, which lists the values coming from end point in rows. I want to give color of rows based on a JSON value. Angularjs plnkr link :-

http://plnkr.co/edit/X8L5WwbIVWNzjoLxoHTg?p=preview

JSON structure :-

```
{
  "1": {
    "venture": "XYZ Informatics",
    "member": [
      {
        "name": "abcd",
        "email": "abcd@gmail.com"
      }
    ],
    "message": "This is good day",
    "isclicked": true
  },
  "2": {
    "venture": "BBC Informatics",
    "member": [
      {
        "name": "xyz",
        "email": "xyz@gmail.com"
      }
    ],
    "message": "This is bad day",
    "isclicked": false
  }
}
```

Output will show :-

```
XYZ Informatics
BBC Informatics
```

I want to give green color of row if `"isclicked": true` and red color when `"isclicked": false`

As an example `XYZ Informatics` row color should be green and `BBC Informatics` in red.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a function like the following for retrieving the color:

```
  $scope.getColor = function(el) {
        if (!el.isclicked) {
          return {'color': 'red'};
        } else {
          return {'color': 'green'};
        }
      };
```

in this way it's possible to assign the color on the html in this way:

```
      <tr ng-repeat="data in datas">
        <td ng-style="getColor(data)">{{ data.venture }}</td>
      </tr>
```

Updated example: http://plnkr.co/edit/Y2rSF1h372vYQZzG4FPN?p=preview

Comment: This is working answer. I will accept it after 4 mints. Is there any way if I want to give this color to row background, not just text ?

Comment: If you do it with the Angular way, you don't have to write any line of JS.

Comment: I don't think that the use of the logic in a template is a good practice

Answer (score 0):

Use [**`ng-style`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle) directive

```
ng-style="{color:data.isclicked?'green':'red'}" 
//"background-color" if background is to be changed!
```

### [Working Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/fFTWO4?p=preview)

Comment: It is not working. Instead it is showing the red color for both text value. Background color is not working.

Comment: @Codelife, In your sample JSON(_Which you had provided_), both the `isclicked` are `false`.. I have updated my answer though...

Comment: But, it is changing the color of text, I want to change the color of row background.

Comment: @Codelife, Well in that case you are suppose to read the comment under `syntax`.. It is just a css property __`"background-color"`__

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use Angular's [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass).

```
<p ng-repeat="i in items" ng-class="{ green: i.isClicked, red: !i.isClicked }">{{i.venture}}</p>
```

And define your CSS classes red and green:

```
.red {
    background-color: red;
}

.green {
    background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-class for this.

```
ng-class="{green: data.isclicked, red: !data.isclicked}"
```

Don't forget the css-classes for "green" and "red". ;-)

Comment: Aww, i'm too late... ;-P

Answer (score 0):

```
<td ng-class="{'green' : data.isclicked,  'red' : !data.isclick/>
```

CSS

```
.green {
   color: green;
 }

.red {
   color: red;
 }
```